# mysql IN clause not using possible keys

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a fairly simple mysql query which contains a few inner join and then a where clause. I have created indexes for all the columns that are used in the joins as well as the primary keys. I also have a where clause which contains an IN operator. When only 5 or less ids are passed into the IN clause the query optimizer uses one of my indexes to run the query in a reasonable amount of time. When I use explain I see that the type is range and key is PRIMARY. My issue is that if I use more than 5 ids in the IN clause, the optimizer ignores all the available indexes and query runs extremely slow. When I use explain I see that the type is ALL and the key is NULL.

Could someone please shed some light on what is happening here and how I could fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far =) possibly your table schema and query..

Comment: Does this happen as well when you use several OR statements instead of IN?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Yes! It behaves the exact same way when I replace IN with ORs.

Comment: Weird. What is the table engine? MyISAM or InnoDB? Additionally, have you tried the "ANALIZE TABLE" command?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the "primary key" indexes on the tables to optimize the JOINs, you should also have an index based on common criteria you are applying a WHERE against.  More info needed on columns of your query, but you should have an index on your WHERE criteria TOO.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using Mysql Index Hints. It lets you specify which index should be used during the query execution.

Examples:

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

-

```
SELECT * FROM table1 IGNORE INDEX (col3_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

More Information here: 
[Mysql Index Hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found this while checking up on a similar problem I am having. Thought my findings might help anyone else with a similar issue in future.

I have a MyISAM table with about 30 rows (contains common typos of similar words for a search where both the possible original typo and the alternative word may be valid spellings, the table will slowly build up in size). However the cutoff for me is that if there are 4 items in the IN clause the index is used but when 5 are in the IN clause the index is ignored (note I haven't tried alternative words so the actual individual items in the IN clause might be a factor). So similar to the OP, but with a different number of words.

*Use index* would not work and the index would still be ignored. *Force index* does work, although I would prefer to avoid specifying indexes (just in case someone deletes the index).

For some testing I padded out the table with an extra 1000 random unique rows the query would use the relevant index even with 80 items in the IN clause.

So seems MySQL decides whether to use the index based on the number of items in the IN clause compared to the number of rows in the table (probably some other factors at play though).